# Is it OK for SEO to write page titles with the company name in English but the keywords in some other language?

Tags: seo, keywords, title, multilingual, internationalization

Does writing  titles in pages of the form:

> company name in English | keyword in page language | keyword in page language

Have bad effect on SEO?

Comment: When you have two different keywords are they in different languages?  Like "company name in English | keyword in French | keyword in German"? or are we just talking about a company name in English with one other language: "company name in English | keyword in French | keyword in French"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The last one

Comment: Does the company have different names in different languages, and you wonder if it’s better to use the non-English name? If not, why is this a question you wonder about? The only alternative would be using English keywords in the title for a page that is not in English, and that obviously doesn’t make sense, right?